# How read < abc: xyz > xml tag using php?

Tags: php, xml

Using my below code i can read `<abcxyz>` xml tag easily. but how can i read the data between `<abc:xyz>` `</abc:xml>` xml tag..
xml tag using php.pls help....

my php sample code...

```
 $objDOM->load("abc.xml"); 
  $note = $objDOM->getElementsByTagName("note");  
   foreach( $note as $value )
   {
    $tasks = $value->getElementsByTagName("tasks");
    $task  = $tasks->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $details = $value->getElementsByTagName("details");
    $detail  = $details->item(0)->nodeValue;    
    echo "$task :: $detail<br>";
   }
```

My XML sample code:

```
<mynotes>
     <note>
        <tasks>Task 1</tasks>
        <details>Detail 1</details>
     </note>
     <abc:xyz> Cannot Read the XML data between this tag</abc:xyz>
 </mynotes>
```

Pls guide me...

Thanks
Riad

Comment: What's the class of $objDOM? Can it do XML Namespaces? Because that looks like what `abc` is in the context of the <abc:xyz> tag...

Answer (score 7):

`abc:xyz` means that the element is named `xyz`, and the *namespace* is indicated by `abc`. The namespace part is actually shorthand for an URI, which is usually also given in the XML file. For example, you may see this:

`xmlns:abc="http://www.abc.com/xml"`

In this case, elements which have `abc` before the colon are in the namespace `http://www.abc.com/xml`.

To retrieve this element, you need to use [getElementsByTagNameNS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php) and pass `http://www.abc.com/xml` as the namespace.

Comment: Please check if you can answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665222/unable-to-parse-xml-data-with-colon-from-response-using-getnamespaces

Answer (score 2):

you need [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagNameNS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php)

Comment: could you pls give me an example..because on that link i don't get any proper example..

Comment: using this example i get the abc and xyz into a seperated variable like $v1 and $v2.But i cannot put $value->getElementsByTagName($v1,$v2); on this function to get value between this..I need the value between this tag

Answer (score 1):

Going with the `DOMDocument::getElementsByTagNameNS` way like others have suggested, here is a working code (including reading the inner content), assuming that you also have some namespace declaration (like `<abc:response xmlns:abc="http://api-url">` ) part as pointed out by @Sjoerd -

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
         <abc:response xmlns:abc="http://api-url">
         <mynotes>
          <note>
            <tasks>Task 1</tasks>
            <details>Detail 1</details>
          </note>
         <abc:xyz> Can Read the XML data between this tag!!</abc:xyz>
        </mynotes>
        </abc:response>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
// load the XML string defined above
$dom->loadXML($xml);


foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://api-url', '*') as $element) 
{
  //echo 'see - local name: ', $element->localName, ', prefix: ', $element->prefix, "\n";
  if($element->localName == "xyz")
      echo get_inner_html($element);

}

function get_inner_html( $node ) 
{ 
    $innerHTML= ''; 
    $children = $node->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) 
    { 
        $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child ); 
    } 

    return $innerHTML;  
}
```

[Here](http://codepad.org/TddVk3jK) is a working link showing the output.

Note that I have just wrapped your xml inside this -

```
   '<?xml version="1.0"?>
         <abc:response xmlns:abc="http://api-url">'
              .$yourxml
         .'</abc:response>';
```

I used the solution I got from here [PHP DOM get nodevalue html? (without stripping tags)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286362/php-dom-get-nodevalue-html-without-stripping-tags/6286409#6286409)... was stuck with a similar problem these days.