# PHP DOM get nodevalue html? (without stripping tags)

Tags: php, html, dom

I am trying to get the innerhtml of div tags in a file using nodeValue, however this code is outputting only plain text and seems to strip out all html tag from inside the div. How can I change this code to output the div's HTML content and not plain text, AND also output the main div wrapping it's child elements.

Example:

contents of file.txt:

```
<div class="1"><span class="test">text text text</span></div>
<div class="2"><span class="test">text text text</span></div>
<div class="3"><span class="test">text text text</span></div>
```

script.php:

```
  $file= file_get_contents('file.txt');

    $doc = new DOMDocument();

    @$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">'.$file); 

    $entries = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');

        for ($i=0;$i<$entries->length;$i++) {
            $entry = $entries->item($i);
            echo $entry->nodeValue;
        }
```

outputs: text text texttext text texttext text text

what I need it to output:

```
<div class="1"><span class="test">text text text</span></div>
<div class="2"><span class="test">text text text</span></div>
<div class="3"><span class="test">text text text</span></div>
```

Notice the parent div's (..etc) are needed to be outputted as well wrapping the span tags...

HELP!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I have never done what you're attempting to do, but as a stab in the dark, using the API docs, does echo $entry->textContent; work?

Adding an update.  This is from the comments located on the docs page for [DOMNode](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php):

Hi!

Combining all th comments, the easiest way to get inner HTML of the node is to use this function:

```
<?php  function get_inner_html( $node ) { 
    $innerHTML= ''; 
    $children = $node->childNodes; 
    foreach ($children as $child) { 
        $innerHTML .= $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child ); 
    } 

    return $innerHTML;  }  ?>
```

Or, maybe a simpler method is just to do:

```
echo $domDocument->saveXML($entry);
```

Comment: Sorry, should have included this in the post, but here is where I found this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php  textContent = "This attribute returns the text content of this node and its descendants."

Comment: Nope, this does the same thing as nodeValue

Comment: According to a comment in the docs, traversing is the best way to get the innerHTML.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I have not tested the code you posted but I found this `function innerXML($node) {
    $doc  = $node->ownerDocument;
    $frag = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child)
    {
        $frag->appendChild($child->cloneNode(TRUE));
    }
    return $doc->saveXML($frag);
} 
` and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, not sure I was much help, but hopefully, at the least, pointed you in the right direction.

Comment: @Marty: Please leave a link where you found it.

Comment: I found it here: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/php-34/php5-need-something-like-innerhtml-instead-nodevalue-611393.html

Answer (score 16):

Instead of:

```
echo $entry->nodeValue;
```

You have to use:

```
echo $doc->saveXML($entry);
```

Here is a more complete example that might help others too, `$doccontent` is the HTML block as a string:

```
$doccontent = '<html> …'; // your html string
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // prevent error messages 
$content_utf = mb_convert_encoding($doccontent, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8'); // correct parsing of utf-8 chars
$dom->loadHTML($content_utf);
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors); // prevent error messages 
$specialdiv = $dom->getElementById('xdiv');
if(isset($specialdiv))
{
    echo $dom->saveXML($specialdiv);
}
```