# PHP retrieving XML tagnames

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml, tagname

i am actually new with these XML stuff. I do understand things about the DOMDocument,DOMNOdeList and etc using http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php

so here is the problem..

http://jobhits.co.uk/services/rss?k=job

the feed above returns an XML document. i can successfully retrieve tag names like title,description and link using these codes

```
$doc->load('http://jobhits.co.uk/services/rss?k=job');
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName("item");

foreach($items as $item){
    $titles[] = $item->getElementsByTagName("title");
}
```

the problem is there is a certain *'tagname-like'* in that document

```
<a10:updated></a10:updated>
```

i tried getting that using

```
$update[] = $item->getElementsByTagName("a10:updated");
```

..which is a failure

here is a sample xml http://piratelufi.com/ark/gettagname.xml or you can use the string inside load method above :)

btw i can't use simpleXML and predefined classes as much as possible
thanks :D

Comment: Earlier: [How read < abc: xyz > xml tag using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3130605/367456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [`getElementsByTagNameNS`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagnamens.php),

Comment: fail question guess i haven't read it very well. thank you very much :)

Comment: Well, namespaces are the default problem anyone encounters when just starting out with xml/DOM, you are in good company :)

Answer (score 2):

The `a10` jsut denotes, that the element updated is from a different namespace. The colon `:` is a special character in this context. 
In the beginning of your sample xml (the latter url) one finds the definition of this namespace: `<rss xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">`.
So You need `getElementsByTagNameNS`. I presume something along the lines of: `getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","updated")`might help.

Comment: well explained i'll up this one. so that's what namespaces are in XML xD thank you