# Error when read xml file using php domxml?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, xml-namespaces

I have a file test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
<dc:creator><![CDATA[hello world]]></dc:creator>
</item>
```

and code php

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('test.xml');
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('item');
foreach ($items as $item) {
   $authors = $item->getElementsByTagName( "dc:creator" );
   $author = $authors->item(0)->nodeValue;
   echo $author;
}
```

=> error can't get value, how to get this, result is "hello world"

Comment: "dc" here is a namespace, which does not get considered as part of the "tag name". Try [`getElementsByTagNameNS`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagnamens.php).

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong element name. The method `getElementsByTagName` expects the local-name, that is `creator` in your case.

You can see that if you load your sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item>
<dc:creator><![CDATA[hello world]]></dc:creator>
</item>
```

into the DOMDocument. You get a warning:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Namespace prefix dc on creator is not defined in Entity

Because the namespace prefix is not defined, DOMDocument will remove it. This results in the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<item xmlns:dc="ns:1">
<creator><![CDATA[hello world 2]]></creator>
</item>
```

As you can see there is no element with the *local name* `creator` with an *xmlns-prefix*  `dc` (`<dc:creator>`)any longer.

But as you're like have pasted the wrong XML for your example and likely the namespace prefix *is* defined in your real XML, you're just asking how to access tags with a namespace prefix (that is the part before the colon `:`). This has already been outlined here:

- [How read < abc: xyz > xml tag using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3130605/367456)

If you want an element which's tag is inside a namespace of its own, you need to tell *DOMDocument* which namespace you mean:

```
$dcUri   = $doc->lookupNamespaceUri('dc');
$authors = $item->getElementsByTagNameNS($dcUri, 'creator');
$author  = $authors->item(0)->nodeValue;
```